# Java JDBC efficiency: How long should a connection be maintained?

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, connection

I'm still working on the same problem mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153322/java-swing-postgres-user-authentication-close-old-connection-when-new-connect). It seems to work fine especially after creating an AbstractModel class shown below:

```
public abstract class AbstractModel {

    protected static Connection myConnection = SingletonConnection.instance().establishConnection();
    protected static Statement stmt;
    protected static ResultSet rs;

    protected boolean loginCheck;                   // if userId and userLoginHistoryId are valid - true, else false
    protected boolean userLoggedIn;                 // if user is already logged in - true, else false

    public AbstractModel (int userId, Long userLoginHistoryId){
        createConnection();                                 // establish connection
            loginCheck = false;
        userLoggedIn = false;
        if (userId == 0 && userLoginHistoryId == 0){        // special case for login
            loginCheck = true;                              // 0, 0, false, false
            userLoggedIn = false;                           // set loginCheck to true, userLogged in to false
        } else {
            userLoggedIn = true;
            try{
                String query = "select \"user_login_session_check\"(" + userId + ", " + userLoginHistoryId + ");";
                System.out.println("query: " + query);
                stmt = myConnection.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()){
                    loginCheck = rs.getBoolean(1);
                }
            } catch (SQLException e){
                System.out.println("SQL Exception: ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    // close connection
    public void closeConnection(){
        try{
            myConnection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    // establish connection
    public void createConnection(){
        myConnection = SingletonConnection.instance().establishConnection();
    }

    // login session check
    public boolean expiredLoginCheck (){
        if (loginCheck == false && userLoggedIn == true){
            closeConnection();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

I've already posted the stored procedures and Singleton Pattern implementation in the link to the earlier question above.

I'm under the impression that I don't need to close the connection to the database after each single data transaction, as it would just slow the application. I'm looking at about 30 users for this system I'm building, so performance and usability is important.

Is it correct to prolong the connection for at least 3-4 data transactions? Eg. Validation checks to user inputs for some form, or, something similar to google's auto-suggest ... These are all separate stored function calls based on user input. Can I use one connection instance, instead of connecting and disconnecting after each data transaction? Which is more efficient?

If my assumptions are correct (more efficient to use one connection instance) then opening  and closing of the connection should be handled in the controller, which is why I created the createConnection() and closeConnection() methods.

Thanks.

Comment: If one of these answers explained things clearly enough, you should accept one of them, as this is how Stackoverflow works. Alternatively, you can ask for further clarifications, or update your question.

Answer (score 5):

Your code should never depend on the fact, that your application is currently the only client to the database or that you have only 30 users. So you should handle database connections like files, sockets and all other kinds of scarce resources that you may run ouf of.

Thus you should **always** clean up after yourself. No matter what you do. Open connection, do your stuff (one or SQL statements) and close connection. **Always!**

In your code you create your connection and save it into a static variable - this connection will last as long as your AbstractModel class lives, probably forever - this is bad. As with all similar cases put you code inside try/finally to make sure the connection gets always closed.

I have seen application servers running ouf of connections because of web applications not closing connections. Or because they closed at logout and somebody said "we will never have more then that much users at the same time" but it just scaled a little to high.

Now as you have your code running and closing the connections properly add connection pooling, like zaske said. This will remedy the performance problem of opening/closing database connection, which truely is costly. On the logical layer (your application) you doesn't want to know when to open/close physical connection, the db layer (db pool) will handle it for you.

Then you can even go and set up a single connection for your whole session model, which is also supported by DBCP - this is no danger, since you can reconfigure the pool afterwards if you need without touching your client code.

Comment: +1, although I disagree with the part about keeping the connection in a `static` object as I don't think this will be a very good idea for multiple instances and threading.

Comment: you misunderstood: I plead against it! Statics generally create a global state and are to be avoided if possible.

Comment: Oh, apologies, I seem to have misread. Yeah, you are indeed quite right! :)

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your responses. I created the static myConnection field because it uses the Singleton Pattern to use just one connection instance for any/all queries to the database from the application. By calling myConnection.close(), I seem to close the connection. This is why I added the createConnection() method as simply initializing myConnection to SingletonConnection.instance().establishConnection(); when declaring the field only worked fine until a myConnection.close() statement was called. Thereafter, I have to call createConnection() to connect to the database.

Answer (score 4):

Like Tomasz said, you should **never** ***ever*** depend on the fact that your application will be used by a small number of clients. The fact that the driver ***will*** timeout after a certain amount of time does not guarantee you that you will have enough available connections. Picture this: a lot of databases come pre-configured with a maximum number of connections set to (say) 15 and a timeout of (let's say) 10-15 minutes. If you have 30 clients and each does an operation, somewhere around half-way you'll be stuck short on connections.

You should handle connections, files, streams and other resources the following way:

```
public void doSomething()
{
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    final String sql = "SELECT ....");

    try
    {
        connection = getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if (rs.next())
        {
            // Do something here...
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        closeResultSet(rs);
        closeStatement(stmt);
        closeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

The try/catch/finally guarantees you that the connection will get closed no matter the outcome. If there is some sort of failure, the finally block will still close the connection, just like it would do, if things were okay.

Similarly, with file and streams you need to do the same thing. Initialize the respective object as `null` outside your try/catch/finally, then follow the approach above.

This misconception makes a lot of Java applications misbehave under Windows, where people don't close files (streams to files, etc) and these files become locked, forcing you to either kill the JVM, or even restart your machine.

You can also use a connection pool such as for example Apache's DBCP, but even then you should take care of closing your resources, despite the fact that internally, the different connection pool implementations do not necessarily close the connections.

Comment: Understood. I will add finally clauses wherever there is a connection instance initialized/created, and close it in the finally clause. As for Apache's DBCP, do I need to have Apache running on my Server in order to implement it? Or do I simply need to add some libraries to my Java (front end) project in order for pooling to work? This (http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/PoolingDataSourceExample.java?revision=1143885&view=markup) is what I've noted thus far.

Comment: Say, would adding commons-pool-1.5.6.jar, commons-dbcp-1.3.jar (JDK 1.4-1.5) or commons-dbcp-1.4 (JDK 1.6+) and j2ee.jar (for the javax.sql classes) in addition to the jbbc.jar driver, to only the front end, be sufficient for pooling to be implemented? Or do I need to make changes to my Server setup? I never got to look at this properly because Glassfish's Admin Console created the pool for you in a matter of clicks.

Comment: Well, I believe you don't necessarily need to have a web container running in order to use connection pooling. It really depends on the pooling library you'll be using for this. In most application servers there is support for defining data sources.

An alternative would be to use something like a Spring / Hibernate setup and add (say) Apache DBCP.

I suggest you have a look at a couple of tutorials. It's not really complicated to get it right.

Comment: In Glassfish, I believe you would normally use the JCA and define data sources for it. It really depends on what your environment is.

Comment: Sorry for not getting things quickly, but exactly what do I need to get a connection pool running? Does it have to be installed on the client or server side? Can I run Apache DBCP without an application server installed on the server, from my java front-end application? I'll have a look, but I'm not sure how to set it up without an Application Server like glassfish installed. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.sql.org/sql-database/postgresql/manual/jdbc-datasource.html     "In an environment without an application server, PostgreSQL provides two implementations of DataSource which an application can use directly. One implementation performs connection pooling, while the other simply provides access to database connections through the DataSource interface without any pooling. Again, these implementations should not be used in an application server environment unless the application server does not support the ConnectionPoolDataSource interface."

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't be able to tell you from the top of my head. I've used DBCP in a Spring + Hibernate set up. I would have to consult the documentation myself as well in order to tell you how to do it for a standalone application.

Comment: I'll go through it tonight. Hopefully will get something productive by tomorrow. Most people I've seen rate c3p0 over DBCP. I've downloaded both libraries and am planning to add it to my app and test and see if they work. I'll post my results. Thanks for your patience. I now wish more than ever that Glassfish and EJB were working on my Server.

Answer (score 0):

You'are right that you don't need to close the connection after each call. 
Bare in mind that that modern database implement internal connection pools, but your application still need to connect and retrieve a connection object, and this is what it does now. 
You should consider using a database connection pool - there are various Java frameworks to provide you such a solution, and they will define (you will be able to configure of course) when a database connection pool is closed. 
In general - you should ask yourself whether your database serves only your application, or does it serve other application as well - if it does not serve other application as well, you might be able to be more "greedy" and keep connections open for a longer time. 
I would also recommend that your application will create on start a fixed number of connections (define it in your configuration with a value of "Minimum connections number") and you will let it grow if needed to a maximum connection numbers. 
As I previously mentioned - the ideas are suggest are implemented already by all kinds of frameworks, for example - the [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) project of Apache.

Comment: Thanks for the response zaske. I had originally planned to build the database using EJB and a Glassfish server, but I had problems generating the Entity Classes from a 240-table Postgres database I created ... so had no option but to resort for a simple JDBC connection. Kindly see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891152/ejb-entity-bean-generation-error-from-postges-8-4-using-jpa-2-0-and-eclipselink and the reported bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375728 One advantage I have noted is that the application is much faster without an application server running.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Singleton Pattern which I initialize the myConenction field in all my Models to:

```
public class DatabaseConnection {
    private static final String uname = "*******";
    private static final String pword = "*******";
    private static final String url = "*******************************";

    Connection connection;
    // load jdbc driver
    public DatabaseConnection(){
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            establishConnection();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ce) {
            System.out.println("Could not load jdbc Driver: ");
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Connection establishConnection() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pword);
        } catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Could not connect to database: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}

public class SingletonConnection {

    private static DatabaseConnection con;

    public SingletonConnection(){}

    public static DatabaseConnection instance(){

        assert con == null;
            con = new DatabaseConnection();
        return con;
    }
}
```

Of course each and every connection to the database from the app goes through a Model.