# Postgres SQL Pool Connection without application server

Tags: postgresql, connection, pool

This is me following up on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202046/java-jdbc-efficiency-how-long-should-a-connection-be-maintained) I posted earlier, where I was advised to use a Connection Pool to connect to my Postgres database. According to [Postgres' jdbc4](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/ds/PGPoolingDataSource.html) documentation, they mention that there are two types of pools that can be used. One with an Application Server, and one without an Application Server. I'm planning to not use an Application Server for reasons I'll raise later. I had a quick question about the Connection Pool without an App Server:

> *If you're sure you want to use this, then you must set the properties dataSourceName, databaseName, user, and password (if required for the user). The settings for serverName, portNumber, initialConnections, and maxConnections are optional. Note that only connections for the default user will be pooled! Connections for other users will be normal non-pooled connections, and will not count against the maximum pool size limit.*

**What is the default user? Is it a Postgres Database user/role? Would it be sufficient to add these packages to my front end, and have a Server dedicated to only running Postgres?**

The reason why I'm leaning towards this is because I've worked with Glassfish before, and while connectivity and persistence with a data source was a breeze, I ran into problems generating Entity Classes from an already created Postgres Database (240 tables, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891152/ejb-entity-bean-generation-error-from-postges-8-4-using-jpa-2-0-and-eclipselink) and [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=375728)).

Therefore, I dumped the idea of using EJB and Glassfish and instead used a simple Singleton Pattern with a jdbc connection to connection to my database. **The application is running quite fast, which is why I'm leaning towards not using an Application Server. Is this a correct impression or am I falsely informed?**

Comment: The "default" user is the one defined in the connection pool properties.

Comment: Thanks. If I chose a framework like c3p0, I would just need to add it to my application ... and not change anything on my server, right? My server only have Postgres SQL.

Comment: Correct. The connection pool is only relevant to the application server. PostgreSQL will not know wether the connection is from a pool or not.

Comment: But I don't have an application Server. I have a PostgreSQL Database and a Java Swing application. Thats all. I was referring to adding c3p0 libraries to my front-end application.

Comment: The use the connection pool from your application. The pool doesn't care whether it's called from e.g. Tomcat or your application.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up. I will do more reading and post my results/solution.

Answer (score 0):

First there is way too little information there to determine whether an application server would help or not.  usually it is less of a speed issue and more of a matter of re-using logic in different applications throughout the enterprise.

Secondly for connection pooling what you have to remember is that you can't re-use a connection for one user as another user.  So you expect to have, typically, a connection pool under a single application user.  This gets configured at the connection pool level.  you could have several connection pools connecting different applicatins to the db under different users.